# php webservices Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, boolean

Iam getting a boolean from a webservices, var_dump:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["CheckIfUserCridentialsAreValidResult"]=> bool(false) }
```

i tried to put it in a if statement, like this:

```
if($response)
   echo "TRUE";
else 
   echo "FALSE";
```

because if i just do:

```
echo $response;
```

But then I get this message:

> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string".

I tried to strictly define the variable as a Boolean, but that also didn't work. I think i need to do an extra step, i just can not find that extra step on Google or on Stack overflow.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: iam getting a Boolean from a webservice, and then I want to work with it like a Boolean created in a normal php script. if i put the variable in a if statement. It sees it as alwase TRUE so even if the Boolean that i get from the webservices is FALSE.. But i dont know how to get the TRUE or FALSE from the BOolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($response->CheckIfUserCridentialsAreValidResult) { ...
```